# iphone: Unable to connect the outlet?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios4

I am trying to connect UITextField to file's owner. 
Though i have taken

```
  IBOutlet UITextField *txt1
```

But i am not able to connect the outlet

[image]

Can you please suggest what could be wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My suggestion is checking the type of the file's owner.

It should be exactly the same type as the class where you declared `IBOutlet UITextField *txt1`.

Also, ensure that IB knows about the outlet (i.e., it lists it in the outlet pane for your file's owner).

Answer (score 1):

From the popup you have open, click and drag from the circle next to `New Referencing Outlet` to the `File's Owner`. If you can't see an option for `txt1`, click on the rightmost of the three buttons above the label `View` in the top bar. The right pane will appear In the right pane, click the third icon from the left (on the top), and make sure the `Class` under the `Custom Class` heading is set to the same class as the file's owner.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes there is a problem with the class file name. In my case I made a refactory (rename) and forgot to change the custom class attribute for the file's owner, as show in the screen shoot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not declared `@property` in `.h` file and synthesize it..

u may require to declare property  in .h file like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *txt1;
```

and synthesize in `.m` file like this..

```
@synthesize txt1;
```

make sure "`@synthesize txt1`" comes after `@implementation`..

I hope that will help according to my knowledge.. :)